# why does conda downloads python again, when i have anaconda already

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

i am using anaconda python

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)

$ which python
/home/vimal/anaconda2/bin/python

$ conda create -n myjunkproject python=2
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /home/vimal/anaconda2/envs/siraj-regression:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

openssl:    1.0.2l-0     
pip:        9.0.1-py27_1 
python:     2.7.13-0     
readline:   6.2-2        
setuptools: 27.2.0-py27_0
sqlite:     3.13.0-0     
tk:         8.5.18-0     
wheel:      0.29.0-py27_0
zlib:       1.2.8-3      

Proceed ([y]/n)? n
```

why install `python 2.7.13` again?????? isnt it already there? same about `pip`

Comment: why does it downloads the packages, which are already there. thats the question i am asking.

Comment: What version of python is the original one?

Comment: it is `Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)`. Edited the question, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

> Conda treats Python the same as any other package, so it’s very easy to manage and update multiple installations.

According to the Conda documentation here: https://conda.io/docs/py2or3.html

Looks like Conda does this intentionally so that it's easier to update/manage multiple installations of python.

Hope that helps.

Comment: it can treat python as just another package, fine. but it MADATORILY DOWNLOADS every single dependency, why cannot it cache and reuse?

Comment: Looks like an issue similar to yours has been discussed in Conda's github issues: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1967

Comment: From the looks of it, it seems as though Conda's dependency resolver (when updating in their case) is a bit wonky. It's probably treating the "python=2" argument as "python=2*" (automatically looking for the latest python 2).
You could try using python=2.7.13 although I'm not sure if that will fix the issue.

Hope that provides some more insight.